# Database locked in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, versioning, google-cloud-datastore

I was running two different versions of my app with the same api_version number, and I started receiving Database locked exception. I've closed both apps, removed both from the app engine launcher, and then reloaded the one i'm currently working on; and I'm still getting the same error.

I've been googling it for 30 minutes, and it doesn't seem like there is a lot of information on this topic specifically related to GAE.

I would like to know how to go about fixing the issue, but more than that, I'd like to know what's causing it in the first place.

I gave to 2 api versions different version numbers but the same api number with the hope that I'd be able to run them concurrently and have them share a datastore instance, but if its displaying this behavior locally, I'm sure its not going to work when deployed. I suppose I have less of an understanding of the versioning than I thought. If anyone has a brief explanation of that process, what causes locking and how to fix that would be great. Thanks!

EDIT:

'api_version' refers to google's api for app engine; nothing to do with one's personal application. still trying to figure out how to deal with 'version' and @endpoints.api. What's the diff?

Comment: Maybe not a definite answer, but I do have issues myself with `python`  runtime hanging after running the dev server (this occurs with `dev_appserver.py` behind the scenes on the launcher) - I have to do a nasty `killall python -QUIT` from time to time to deal with the port being double bound, might explain a database lock issue.

Comment: Yeah, I have to do the same thing. Doesn't seem like too good of a long term solution haha